# Redux createStore error: Expected the reducer to be a function

Tags: redux, redux-thunk, redux-promise-middleware

I'm getting an error on `createStore` and I'm not understanding why.

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from "redux-thunk"
import promise from "redux-promise-middleware"
import * as reducers from './reducers';

const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk);

export default createStore(reducers, middleware);
```

Above is my code and I get the error in the line

```js
const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk);
```

The error is **Expected the Reducer to be a function**.
I'm using React Native 0.37 and the latest version of redux, redux-thunk and redux-promise-middleware.
The reducers is the result of combineReducers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the reducer code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import * as reducers from './reducers';
```

There's no way that `reducers` is a function. You're going to get an object with each export as a property. You probably want:

```
import reducers from './reducers';
```